# Critical Error of : file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.in my Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, frontend, redirect

Here I explained the issue in detail:

> *: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/:/tmp/) in /var/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge/src/Autoloader.php*

This error shows in admin login page:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/:/tmp/) in
> /var/www/domain.com/public_html/vendor/laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge/src/Autoloader.php on line 69

Your issue is similar to [Magento 2 error: open_basedir restriction in effect](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/357920/magento-2-error-open-basedir-restriction-in-effect).

To find the root cause of the issue, you can add an Xdebug breakpoint prior to line 69 or use the [`debug_print_backtrace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) function to print the backtrace.

However, `open_basedir` often causes more trouble for Magento than it’s worth. It can lead to degraded performance because Magento relies on numerous files working together across several directories. It's therefore recommended to disable the `open_basedir` function on the server hosting your Magento site. You can find more information about this on NexCess blog at https://www.nexcess.net/blog/php-open-basedir/

Comment: hello @Tu Van Thank you so much for answer it's answer also 100% work for me but can i get anymore solution instead of disable open_basedir function on the server. –

Comment: Hi @JayParmar. Yep, I've pointed out the direction to address it in my answer: finding the root cause of the issue, which may be caused by a custom module or a third-party extension. You can then resolve it.